Ads test beginning December 3, 2024
We’ve been exploring the concept of using open auction to manage advertising on some Stack Exchange sites. Under this model, advertisers (who have been organized into categories based on their products) “bid” for an advertising spot. There is a floor price - a minimum price for the spot, and all bids must exceed that floor price.  This community will be testing the open auction experiment, beginning on December 3, 2024.  For more information or to provide feedback on the experiment, please refer to the post on Meta Stack Exchange.

Gotta love how they see us as "inventory".

I’m voting to close this question because I want to show my distaste in as many different avenues of protest against this as possible

@TheDemonLord Closed or not, the WB.SE community is not in a position where a "No" will be heeded, and we're not exactly in a position to act against this unwelcome intrusion into our community.

@MontyWild I've often wondered how our SE Overlords would react if we organized a peaceful but highly dirsuptive sit-in at their coroprate offices. It's hard to believe in today's world where everybody wants a cause to protest but no one wants to lift a finger beyond complaining on social media whether such a protest could be organized... but it would make our point (and probably drive away advertisers). Oh well... one can dream. Maybe WB.SE will warrant another Tweet telling us "Bye!" And we've lost so many of our senior members already.

@JBH As I'm almost literally on the other side of the world, that's not an option for me... but you're welcome to try to organise one, if it is an option for you.  It's not like I could moderate you from here...

So the first advert I notice is preaching that hypersexuality isn't infidelity, but an ADHD responce [sic.]. A lot of teens use this stack, @Philippe. Good thing we're teaching them to rationalize bad behavior and bad spelling. This particular ad has been lampooned all over the Internet. Good thing your priorities are so obvious or we'd have to question them.

@JBH I think that would make a good post on Meta

This is insult upon injury
When you took away the community ads you took away the single most powerful method we had to draw the community into Meta and better collaborate as a community. Now you're replacing them with ads that are only valuable because of our content. To quote from an answer I gave a long time ago in response to our SE Overlords firing Monica Cellio:

All this has reminded me of a lesson I learned in a small company many years ago.  Farmers don't need kings.  But kings desperately need farmers.
If that doesn't make sense, permit me to explain.  Royalty (kings, aka "management") is comparatively useless.  It produces nothing.  It has as its only benefit the ability to oversee and organize to improve efficiency or to bring about a collaborative benefit such as group pricing for products.  But by themselves, kings are incapable of producing enough value to justify their own existence.
Farmers, on the other hand, are mega-producers.  They produce the food to feed nations.  Farmers are the foundation of society.  Without someone growing the food, everyone else can't do what they want to do.
When the two are in sync, kings and farmers can do amazing things.  When they're not in sync, the king invariably believes he's more important than the farmers.  The farmers, of course, know better.
Stack Overflow, Inc. is the king who desperately needs the farmer.
The community is the farmer who doesn't need the king.
SO.inc has developed an incredibly cool and useful website/platform/service.  But without the vast community of contributors, it's worthless.  And contributors can go anywhere to contribute.  Without the value other people bring to SO.inc, SO.inc has nothing to offer to anybody.
And it appears SO.inc has forgotten that simple, important fact.

Somebody made plenty of money selling all our freely-given content to develop any number of chatbots, demonstrating you're more than capable of monetizing our goodwill without forcing us to put up with banner ads.
So please do us a favor, Philippe, VP of Community, and fight for our community rather than acting as a shill for the powers who constantly treat their greatest asset as chattel.

@philippe --- Wisdom. Be attentive!

No.

That is all.

According to the linked thread, you all tried to jam ads down our throats five years ago. We already give you FREE expertise, FREE research, FREE answer development, essentially all FREE labour. We also  create, improve & curate content as well as manage the user experience of SE for anyone who comes here to find answers. At a base rate of 250 to 500 USD  per hour, you're getting a very good deal. You don't pay us near enough to put up with this kind of BS. Give it up.

If Stack Exchange has to shove ads at users who generate a great deal of unpaid content, then there's something fundamentally wrong with SE's business model.  Isn't SE selling private Q&A sites (Teams) for profit?  Why is that not enough?  Does this move to ads mean that SE's business model is fundamentally flawed, and that we had all better look elsewhere for a Q&A community before SE goes into receivership and closes up shop... Codidact, perhaps?
If we have to put up with ads, then users whose content attracts views and ad-clicks should be eligible to receive a share of the revenue... in cash.  After all, the user generated the content, and without it, there would be no view and no click.  Show ads to the content consumers, and pay the content producers.  There's a business model for you... but didn't Stack Exchange show that the Experts Exchange paid model didn't work as well?
Or else go back to the current ad-free status quo.

I do not like this idea.
I think it is a bad idea.
Ad Banners are at best a mere nuissance and at worst have made me stop using various sites.
There is not really much more to say, other than to re-iterate the views of my esteemed fellow world builders.
